# Advanced Custom Fields - Toggleable Options for the Backend?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a website using the ACF plugin (Version 5 Pro), and I'm setting up a button on a page template, which by itself isn't the problem.  The problem is that depending on the specific content of each individual page using that template, the button can have one of several different appearances.  What I'm trying to do is set things up so that I can upload all the buttons into the default value section of the ACF field ahead of time, and then every time I make a new page using that template, simply select the appropriate button from a radio button, a dropdown menu, or something similar on the backend of the page.  I plan to be constantly uploading small amounts of content using this template, so not having to manually select the appropriate images on each page would save me a lot of time.

I've googled around and there wasn't a good answer I could find anywhere, so I'm hoping one of you more knowledgeable folks could help me out!

(And before anyone proposes this as a solution, no, the content of each page isn't something I can define just using programming.  It's a little more abstract and needs human input.  If all else fails I can just make multiple templates and simply select the appropriate one when I go to make a page, but the way I'm trying to do it now would be a lot cleaner).

Answer (score 0):

You can try ACF Flexible Content:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/flexible-content-field/

Using Flexible Content field, you will be able to create multiple fields (button 1, button 2, etc) including a WYSIWYG editor and build the buttons HTML adding the default value of the field.

You can read: 
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/html-default-values/

However, I think you'll get in trouble making your buttons dynamic with this approach...  so I'd suggest it will be better if you keep some parts of the buttons (like URLs) dynamic, using an extra field to enter the URL, anchor, etc.